# Workflow Foundation and Azure

Tags: azure, workflow-foundation-4, azure-appfabric

I have been looking into Workflow Foundation for a build we are currently undertaking.

I have a proof of concept and have been using IIS AppFabric for tracking, faults, and persistence to SQL which are key to our new build. We are now looking to Azure for the hosting of the workflow service, which i have working but cannot find any guides on how to set up the monitoring IIS AppFabric offers in terms of database setup.

I have read that AppFabric will no longer be supported as of this year, does this include Azure AppFabric. What is the best approach in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server AppFabric is retired since 11/04/2017: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appfabric/2015/04/02/microsoft-appfabric-1-1-for-windows-server-ends-support-422016/

My recommendation: You should write your workflow using Azure Logic Apps. It already offers tracking mechanisms that uses Azure Storage accounts.